# Чтение форматированных данных

Tags: c

На ввод дается две строки вида `a*b'c"`

(0<= a <= 180) (0<=b<=59) (0<=c<=59)

Необходимо сложить их и результат вывести в в таком же виде.

Пример:
Ввод:

```
1*5'46"
2*10'15"
```

Вывод:

```
3*16'1"
```

Я попытался решить, но не понимаю что сделать в sscanf()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
int main()
{
   int a,b,c,d,e,f,i,q,p;
   char *s[15];
   char *w[15];
    scanf("%s",&s);
    scanf("%s",&w);
sscanf(s, "%d*%d\'%d\"",&a,&b,&c);
sscanf(w, "%d*%d\'%d\"",&d,&e,&f); 
i =  a+d;
q =  b+e;
p =  c+f;
if (p > 59){
    p = c + f - 59;
    q = b + e + 1;
    if ((q)>59){
        q = b + e - 59;
        i = a + d + 1;
        printf("%d*%d\'%d\"",a,b,c);
    }
    else{
        printf("%d*%d\'%d\"",i,q,p);
    }
    
}
else{
    printf("%d*%d\'%d\"",i,q,p);
}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему `if ((q)>59){` внутри `if (p > 59){`? Это ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо чтения в строку можно сразу разбирать данные из входного потока.

Чтение данных желательно контролировать.

Именуйте переменные в соответствии с предметной областью - degrees, minutes, seconds.

Правильно считайте переносы в старшие разряды.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int d1, m1, s1;
    if (scanf("%d*%d\'%d\"", &d1, &m1, &s1) != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int d2, m2, s2;
    if (scanf("%d*%d\'%d\"", &d2, &m2, &s2) != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int s3 = s1 + s2;
    int m_carry = s3 / 60;
    s3 %= 60;

    int m3 = m1 + m2 + m_carry;
    int d_carry = m3 / 60;
    m3 %= 60;

    int d3 = d1 + d2 + d_carry;

    printf("%d*%d\'%d\"\n", d3, m3, s3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо всего-лишь правильный тип массива поправить, не массив указателей :

```c
char * s [ 15 ] ;
char * w [ 15 ] ;
```

, а массив букв :

```c
char s [ 15 ] ;
char w [ 15 ] ;
```

и всё будет работать.

Дальше надо проверять на ошибки ввода :

```c
int sr = sscanf(s, "%d*%d\'%d\"",&a,&b,&c);
```

и если `sr != 3` , то был неправильный ввод.